# Session files in emacs.d folder

Tags: session

There are files like `session.10110ac205e127d7e2143131143297155100000021880037` in my `.emacs.d` folder. I would like to do something about it but could not figure out what to do.

- What are these files for ?
- Why emacs generate multiple files ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are saved session files which emacs dumps when the window manager notifies it that it is shutting down. See the function `emacs-session-save`. There are multiple files because they are suffixed by the X session ID. Are you by chance in the habit of quitting your window manager before you exit emacs?

Comment: That sounds right. However, I cannot find `emacs-session-save` function. Is there anything I should load into emacs ?

Comment: @RangiLin: C-h f emacs-session-save should take you there. It's in lisp/term/x-win.el if you have the Emacs source code. According to git the function has been there since 2002 so it's quite old ;-)

Comment: It took me awhile to realize that emacs need to load `term` (or M-x term to load) in order to find this function, `emacs-session-filename` is the function that decide where the file should be saved.  I will take some time to see how I can change it.   Thanks.

Comment: How do we stop them from being made (or move them to another directory)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a movement to clean up this kind of litter of files in `.emacs.d`:

[emacscollective/no-littering: Help keeping ~/.emacs.d clean](https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering)

This issue has been addressed to some degree by [emacs-session: theme emacs-session-filename (#38) by DamienCassou · Pull Request #39 · emacscollective/no-littering](https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering/pull/39/files) but I think it simply puts the files in a subdirectory of `.emacs.d`

This still doesn't address the underlying question of why empty files are being left around. (Yes - for me, all 84 `session.*` files are empty. And yes, I don't bother exiting emacs before shutting down - I just run `(desktop-save-in-desktop-dir)`)

Comment: no-littering is a ambitious approach, however still making too many mistakes. Hence, we need a session* files specialized solution.